# Change MKPinAnnotationView AFTER inital drop

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mapkit

I'm using using iOS Mapkit to drop pins representing packages. Everything works well for the initial load.

What I need to do is when the user location is in a radius of 100m of the nearest package, I need to change the pin to the "unlocked" state (it could be only a color change for now). I already detect the nearest package, I just need to update the associated pin!

What's the easiest way to update a pin after it was dropped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove it using `removeAnnotation:` and re-add it again with the new properties using `addAnnotation:`

Comment: and if I don't want it to drop from the sky again?

Comment: Change its animatesDrop property as well as its color when you add it again.

Comment: you would remove it from the mapview, set a property in my custom MKAnnotation class like pin.unlocked = YES; and then I just add it back to the map, and in my method mapView:viewForAnnotation: I just check if the unlocked property is set, and change color + annimation according to that? Is my logic correct?

Comment: That sounds correct. Please reply back with whether it works well like that or not.